Using Redis to store Socket.io sessions but getting "Session ID unknown"
When I have more than one instance running my socket.io receives the following error "{"code":1,"message":"Session ID unknown"}". This is expected as subsequent requests could be going to dfferent instances.
I managed to set up redis pub/sub to scale to multiple instances but when I try store the session in Redis I am still getting the same "Session ID unknown" issue.
Code below works with one instance but more than one I started to see that error. I know I can use sticky sessions to get this to work but I would rather has session persisted in Redis.
Here is my code, am I missing anything?
sessionMiddleware.js
const session = require("express-session");
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis').default;
const { createClient } = require("redis");

const redisClient = createClient({ url: process.env.REDIS_URL });
redisClient.connect().catch(console.error);

const sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: "secret-key",
    credentials: true,
    name: "sid",
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? true : "auto",
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "none" : "lax",
    },
});

module.exports = { sessionMiddleware };

server.js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
}));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(sessionMiddleware);

const server = app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log(`Started, server is running on port ${port}`);
});

socket.js
let io = socket(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
        credentials: true
    }
});


io.use((socket, next) => {
    sessionMiddleware(socket.request, {}, err => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Session middleware error", err);
            return next(new Error("Internal server error"));
        }
        next();
    });
});

io.use((socket, next) => {
    if (socket.handshake.query && socket.handshake.query.token) {
        jsonwebtoken.verify(socket.handshake.query.token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                return next(new Error('Authentication error'));
            }
            socket.decoded = decoded;
            next();
        });
    } else {
        next(new Error('Authentication error'));
    }
});

frontend connection code
  socket = await io.connect(
    'ws://localhost:4000', 
    {
      query: { token }, 
      reconnection: true,
      reconnectionDelay: 1000,
      reconnectionDelayMax : 5000,
      reconnectionAttempts: Infinity,
      withCredentials: true,
    });

